# Azure App Service, App Service plan, DB (Paas) location and subscription migration

Tags: azure, paas, azure-migrate

Need to move Azure resources (PaaS) from one Location (North Europe) to other (West Europe).

Is it possible using Azure DevOps Pipeline, IaC? Any road blocks or challenges in this?

**Azure Resources:**

- App Service
- App Service Plan
- App Insights
- Availability test
- Database (PaaS)

**Existing:**

- Subscription: A
- Location: North Europe

**Target:**

- Subscription: B
- Location: West Europe

Answer (score 0):

Most resources in Azure cannot be moved from one region to another. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/region-move-support) for the (short) list of resources that do support cross-region move.

You will need to recreate the resources in the new region.